# Recognizing a HTTP access vulnerability scan

Tags: security, apache-2.2, http

I am trying to automatically monitor my apache logs and recognize if someone is doing a vulnerability scan on my web server.

The point of this will be to then route the source IP to a honeypot server instead where I will log all packets coming in.

I have looked around, but haven't been able to find a good answer.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the best solution is a Web Application Firewall like [Mod_Security](http://www.modsecurity.org/).  This can be setup to log vulnerability scans,  but its better to block them.

Comment: Mod_Security looks like it will work for what we are wanting.